# define function with html output in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to define class in `React` with `Typescript` which has a method with html output. but get error about output type of function.

```
interface StateProps {
  page: string,
}
class App extends React.Component<StateProps,any> {
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.pageContent(this.props.page)}
      </div>
    );
}
pageContent = (page:string) => {
    switch (page) {
      case "newPage":
         return <NewPage />;

      case "otherPage":
         return <OtherPage />;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

error was:
`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

eslint suggest use `DetailedHTMLProps<HtmlAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,HTMLDivElement>` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have @types/react in your package.json you should be able to do

```
pageContent = (page:string): ReactNode | null => { 
  ... 
}
```

You probable want to return null instead of breaking. Typescript doesn't like types with optional return.

Comment: this made new error: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.`

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace ?

Comment: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal' has no compatible call signatures.  TS2349`

Comment: That must be an error in another part of your code. Maybe where you use the App component, or in one of the child components.

Comment: you said true. make project again and problem solved. thanks